# Android HttpsURLConnection vs HttpClient, both give problems

Tags: android, json, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I read that HttpsURLConnection is buggy before 2.3 and I have firsthand experience with it being buggy.

The alternate that I tried is HttpClient, however it gives me problems in the sense that it returns me this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

when I'm clearly supposed to get back JSON.

HttpsURLConnection returns JSON back fine but has some inconsistent results when dealing with many requests. (By return JSON, I mean that the response is supposed to contain JSON)

Any idea why HttpClient gives back some xml tag instead of JSON (what should be returned) ?

*EDIT -- CODE*

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    List<NameValuePair> urlParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&platform=","Android"));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&action=","signin"));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&user",username));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&pass",password));



    try {

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParams, HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                resp.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("------>", line);
            ja = new JSONArray(line); //breaks here because it returns xml instead of JSON

        }
        rd.close();
        return ja;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Are there any better alternates to these two?

Comment: I dont know if it matters but the site is https, not http

Comment: first tell me it is .net services or php?

Comment: the code thats supposed to return JSON is written in php

Comment: Don't Mind,do your Url gives JSON output when you manually try it in Desktop Browser?

Comment: @Frankenstein , yes it does; works great in browser and with httpsurlconnection

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a response from the server of an error page. You might be getting a 404 error or many other http errors. This is just the beginning of the html file you are getting back from the server. Are you sure the url is a valid url and will accept a connection from mobile without redirecting?

Comment: Yeah thats the problem, it works completely fine with HttpsURLConnection, and thats only the one line that it returns. Just that xml bit.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `"&"` character from the `BasicNameValuePair key`.

`BasicNameValuePair` autometically append `"&"` in each parameter so no need to add `"&"` character

You have to write as below

```
urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("platform","Android"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 List<NameValuePair> urlParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&platform=","Android"));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&action=","signin"));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&user",username));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&pass",password));
```

Try this:

```
 List<NameValuePair> urlParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("platform","Android"));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action","signin"));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",username));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass",password));
```

Update 1:

What exactly are you trying to implement here:

```
 String line = "";
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("------>", line);
            ja = new JSONArray(line); //breaks here because it returns xml instead of JSON

        }
```

It obvious gives error because you are trying to create JSONArray from the XML response string, intsead check this [public JSONArray (String json)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29) function and implement it.

Comment: @lazeR any response? show logcat output or response, it would be better to get exact.

Comment: the response is only one line: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> and the errors are nullpointerexceptions because the JSON array isn't created since XML isn't JSON format

Comment: Paresh, I know that it breaks because I'm trying to create a JSONArray but it's not supposed to return an XML response string. Thats the problem